MLflow RestAPI does not accept query parameters
as I am getting into MLFlow I try to get some minimal server running and query the RestAPI.
For this I run:
mlflow server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
Then I run the healthcheck curl http://localhost:5000/health and it returns OK.
Next I want to query the experiments that exist in my MLFlow backend (https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#search-experiments):
curl http://localhost:5000/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/search?max_results=5
And it returns a list of the experiments.
Then I try the same with the Python requests module (and also via Postman):
import requests
url = "http://localhost:5000/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/search?max_results=5"
x = requests.post(url)

# Response
{"error_code": "INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE", "message": "Bad Request. Content-Type header is missing."}

So I try again with setting the Content-type:
import requests
url = "http://localhost:5000/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/search"
headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
params = {"max_results": 5}
x = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=params)

# Response
{"error_code": "INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE", "message": "Invalid value 0 for parameter 'max_results' supplied. It must be a positive integer"}

Probably it is my lack of understanding the details of API requests regarding the content-type, but what am I not seeing here?
